# Resetar valor de um campo select com jQuery/Boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, select, formulário, bootstrap

Olá, como posso fazer pra resetar um campo select?

```
<label for="IDSelect">Campo</label>
<select data-live-search="true" title="--" name="NAMESelect" id="IDSelect">
    <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

Vejam que o valor padrão ao carregar a página é "--", quero que após selecionar uma opção e submeter esse formulário (submeto com jquery), volte ao valor padrão "--"

Comment: Quando escreves que _"o valor padrão ao carregar a página é "--""_ dá-me ideia que estás a usar um plugin para selects. É esse o caso? qual?

Comment: estou usando bootstrap

Comment: Podes montar um jsFiddle com um exemplo? o Boostrap está a usar o atributo title como uma option?

Comment: posso, espere uns minutos que estou montando, e não sei utilizar muito bem

Comment: pronto, veja só:

https://jsfiddle.net/t0u1j6L8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer reset ao select do boostrap tens de fazer:

```
$('select').val('').selectpicker('refresh');
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0u1j6L8/2/

Com o `.val('')` dizes que o valor deve ser apagado e com `.selectpicker('refresh')` fazes ele refrescar-se :)

([também podias usar assim](https://jsfiddle.net/t0u1j6L8/3/), com `.trigger('change')`)

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!